# PHP PDO Stored procedure failed when set ATTR_ERRMODE ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I have a problem with PHP PDO,

The following stored procedure does not work when setting ERRMODE to ERRMODE_EXCEPTION (always returns an empty result set)

This is the PHP code:

```
        $id = 12;
        $sql = "CALL get_section_path( ? )";
        
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

        $statement->bindParam( 1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            
        $statement->execute();

        $result_array = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $statement->closeCursor();
```

This is the stored procedure code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_section_path`(IN `p_section_id` INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE d_title_ar VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE d_title_en VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE d_child_type INT;
    DECLARE d_parent_id INT;

    DECLARE cur_section CURSOR FOR SELECT `section_id`, `title_ar`, `title_en`, 1 AS `child_type`, `parent_id` FROM `sections` WHERE section_id = p_section_id;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `sections_temp` (
      `section_id` int(11),
      `title_ar`    varchar(255),
      `title_en`    varchar(255),
      `child_type`  tinyint(1),
      `parent_id`   int(11)
    );

    loop_label: LOOP
        IF p_section_id > 0 THEN
            OPEN  cur_section;
            FETCH cur_section INTO p_section_id, d_title_ar, d_title_en, d_child_type, d_parent_id;
            CLOSE cur_section;
            INSERT INTO `sections_temp` (`section_id`, `title_ar`, `title_en`, `child_type`, `parent_id`) 
                                    VALUES ( p_section_id, d_title_ar, d_title_en, d_child_type, d_parent_id );
            SET p_section_id = d_parent_id;
            ITERATE loop_label;
        ELSE
            LEAVE loop_label;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    SELECT * FROM `sections_temp` WHERE 1;
END
```

I tried to set MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY true/false, but I get the same result.

When I remove ERRMODE_EXCEPTION the procedure working fine.

Test made in PHP version 5.4.45, MySQL version: 5.5.51-38.2, Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

Comment: What is the error message when the exception happens?

Comment: BTW, why don't you use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`? Then you don't need to drop the table, it goes away automatically when you close the connection.

Comment: You don't need a loop to copy the results of a `SELECT` query into another table. You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I didn't get an exception, I get an empty result set

Comment: If you don't get an error, then `ATTR_ERRMODE` should make no difference.

Comment: That's true, but the problem that I use the same class for all other queries and I need to handle errors occurred.

Comment: I mean there must be a different problem in your code. Changing `ATTR_ERRMODE` can't change the results of a query, it only changes how PDO processes errors.

Comment: When I comment this code: `$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` I get the result.

Comment: If that's really true, it means PDO has a serious bug, and I don't see how you can fix it in your script.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I tested it many times, I'm sure. PHP version 5.4.45, MySQL version: 5.5.51-38.2, Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73

Comment: This setting has nothing to do with MySQL, it's handled entirely in PDO.